# How do I initialize a database with one instance of a model in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have a personal portfolio written in RoR, and in it is an "about" page. This "about" page pulls its text from an `Info` model. In other words, I do not want my about page to be a static file. I want to be able to edit its contents.

This raises a concern. I should have exactly **one** instance of the `Info` model in the database as this will be the model displayed on the webpage. It should not be possible to create or delete `Info` models as, again, there should only be one.

How can I ensure that there will only be one instance of this model? How can I have the database "start" with one instance of this model?

Is there a way to add an instance of the `Info` model into the database whenever it is reset?

Comment: You're *mostly* describing seeds created with `rake db:seed`, however it seems more like an error in your modeling.

Comment: Could you suggest a better workflow? I want to have a page with a body of text that I can edit--I do not want it to be static.

Comment: It takes seconds to deploy a new version of a page. I would make it static.

Comment: Is there not a convention for "singleton" models? I'm very new to this, and I'm surprised that there isn't one.

Comment: This sounds like using a lazer gun to slice cheese. I mean you could use a database table to store a single record but using what is basically a content management system for your portfolio is complete overkill. There are static page generators like Jenkins and Middleman that will be way less work and less maintenance